# Проблема с вычислением дисперсии данных

Tags: python, numpy

Учусь быть аналитиком данных. Возникла проблема с подсчетом дисперсии данных. Дисперсия выше чем расположение данных на оси. Все видно на скрине.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прошу прощения, сам вопрос: это нормальное поведение дисперсии?

Comment: Вы можете редактировать свой вопрос. все дополнения и уточнения указывайте в вопросе, а не в комментариях к нему. Кроме того. почитайте, как правильно задать хороший вопрос - например, предоставить пример исходных данных. Ну и все, кроме графика должно быть в вопросе в текстовом виде.

Answer (score 1):

Это хорошо, что вы учитесь. Главное еще - по правильным источникам. Которые объяснят, что "дисперсия" - это величина характеризующая меру разброса случайной величины, как правило - теоретическое. Поскольку вы работает с выборкой, то реально вы можете посчитать среднеквадратичное отклонение, и по нему оценить дисперсию.  Поэтому на скрине никакой дисперсии нет, и увидеть там ее нельзя.

Кстати, в методе var пакета numpy есть такой дивный параметр "ddof=0". Рекомендую хорошенько разобраться как и для чего им пользоваться.

Фраза "Дисперсия выше чем расположение данных на оси." -  вообще загадочная, т.е. дисперсия (и ее оценка) ну никак не связана с "расположением данных на оси".